# Dynamic tables with pdfmake and firebase data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pdfmake

I´m trying to create a dynamic table with pdfmake and Angular5/Ionic3. As table data I need some data from firebase snapshot. So in case I have an observable.

**What I tried**

*Subscribing observable and save data*

```
this.streetDetailData
      .take(1)
      .subscribe(data => {
        bodyData.push(data);
      });
```

*pdfmake definition*

```
content: [
    { text: `${this.sStreet.street}${this.sStreet.parentPLZ ? ', ' +  this.sStreet.parentPLZ : ''}, ${this.sStreet.parentCountry}`, style: 'header' },
    { text: moment().format('LL'), style: 'date'},

    this.table(bodyData, ['number', 'status'])

  ],
```

*table function*

```
table(data, columns) {
    return {
      table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        body: this.buildTableBody(data, columns)
      }
    };
  }
```

*buldTableBody function*

```
buildTableBody(data, columns) {

    let body = [];

    body.push(columns);

    data.forEach((row) => {
      console.log(row);

      let dataRow = [];

      columns.forEach(function(column) {
        dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
      });

      body.push(dataRow);
    });

    return body;
  }
```

But no chance...I´m always getting an empty result... Where´s the error?

**That´s what I see in the generated PDF:**

[image]

Comment: In which line are you getting undefined?

Comment: Oh, I edited my post. I´m not getting "undefined, but just an empty result..

Comment: I'm not sure how pdfmaker works, but you need to trigger that within the subscribe, after the line of code bodyData.push(data);